# Restructuring .js files and directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I recently started on a mobile version of my app I realized that I had no use of all javascript code written for desktop clients. So I put this in `application.html.erb`

```
<% if mobile_agent? %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "mobile" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "mobile", :media => "all" %>
<% else %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "desktop" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "desktop", :media => "all" %>
<% end %>
```

And in app > assets > javascripts I created this structure

```
- desktop.js
- mobile.js
- desktop/file1.js
- desktop/file2.js
- mobile/file1.js
- mobile/file2.js
- shared/file1.js
- shared/file2.js
```

And in mobile.js:

```
//= require_tree ./mobile
//= require_tree ./shared
```

And in desktop.js

```
//= require_tree ./desktop
//= require_tree ./shared
```

In development env that has worked fine, but when I have deployed to Heroku it gives me an error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 100ms
ActionView::Template::Error (mobile.js isn't precompiled):
    8:   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

    11:     <%= javascript_include_tag "mobile" %>
    9: 
    12:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "mobile", :media => "all" %>
    10:   <% if mobile_agent? %>
  Parameters: {"community_category"=>"swingdancing", "city"=>"stockholm"}
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in 78182492067426179_45617280'
    13:   <% else %>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
  app/controllers/communities_controller.rb:20:in `show'
Processing by ErrorsController#show as HTML
    14:    <%= javascript_include_tag "desktop" %>
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:142:in Error during failsafe response: mobile.js isn't precompiled
```

**What is causing this error and how can I resolve it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### what to do ?

simply add

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w(mobile.js)
```

to `config/application.rb`

#### why ?

when you deploy to production environment, by default rails uses the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

This means that instead of serving directly the files that are in `assets/`, rails assumes that you have run `rake assets:precompile` beforehand, and that there are concatenated, compressed and minified versions of your assets in an another folder.

This implies that each and every asset you intend to load from the browser should be precompiled. The benefit is that instead of serving many human-readable files, you only serve a few that have been minified - less connections, less volume = faster load time.

This feature is inactive in development mode because you would have to recompile the assets at each request, and moreover being able to read js and css is quite usefull for debugging.

Comment: Could it be that by removing the standard `application.js` I'm confusing Rails somehow? I have tried to manually/locally precompile the assets with `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but no js-files gets compiled...

Comment: mmm. strange. You should post your conf (anything relevant to asset compression, both in application.rb and production.rb). Maybe there's a conf param that weirds everything out, i don't know